# sql select query guidance required

Tags: sql

I have a table named 'ticket' as given below:

```
number   branchid
3001     1
3002     1
5001     2
7001     2
3001     3
```

All I want to do is that I want to create a new table as:

```
branchid    High-Value      Non-HighValue
```

and I want that when there occurs a number from 3000 series the total count of occurance is listed in High-Value column against its branchid and when ever a 5000 or 7000 series number occur total count of occurance gets listed in non-Highvalue column against its branch id. for example:

```
Branchid    HighValue    non-highvalue
1           2            NULL
2           NULL         2
3           1            NULL
```

Comment: Wich RDBMS are you using? What have you tried, do you have some working query?

Comment: im using mssql. I have tried few but they dont seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

```
select  branchid
,       sum(case when number between 3000 and 3999 then 1 end) as HighValue
,       sum(case when number between 5000 and 5999 then 1 
                 when number between 7000 and 7999 then 1 end) as NonHighValue
from    ticket
group by
        branchid
```

[Live example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eabca/3/0)

Comment: Quick SQL Fiddle tip - you can copy OP's sample data and paste it into the "Text to DDL" tool to quickly generate table definition and insert scripts.  For example, I do so for this question and used your query - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3a29a/1 - this should make answering these that much less tedious.  Cheers!